# setting a correlation id between local and remote queue, use the same to get logs in splunk

Tags: jms, mq

I have two queues. One of them is local and another one is remote.

Generally I use `rfhutil` tool to provide all the details.

By setting `correlationid`, and I do get my logs in splunk using the same.

what should be the appropriate code for that.

Comment: Your question should show some research work at your end. Secondly, you should also read the document of Stackoverflow for how to post questions etc. Best of Luck for your journey!

Comment: Can you confirm if this question is specific to the IBM MQ product?  Unless your application is logging the `correlationid` of the message to somewhere that is being fed into splunk you would not be able to search in splunk, it is not something IBM MQ logs at the queue manager level.

Answer (score 0):

When sending messages:

```
Session session = ...
String  correlationId = ...

TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
msg.setJMSCorrelationID(correlationID);
log.info("Message sent with correlationID: '{}'", correlationId);
```

When receiving messages:

```
MessageConsumer consumer = ...
Message msg = consumer.receiveNoWait();
String correlationId = msg.getJMSCorrelationID();
log.info("Received message with correlationID: '{}'", correlationId);
```

By using Mapped Diagnostic Contex aka [MDC](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) feature of SLF4J you can add correlation ID on every following log line on the same thread:

```
// assume folllowing logback pattern or equivalent for other loggers:
// <pattern>cid: %X{cid} %msg %n</pattern>

String correlationId = "AssumeProperCorrelationIdHere"
org.slf4j.MDC.put("cid", correlationId);
log.info("MDC is a mighty feature");

// expected log output:
// cid: AssumeProperCorrelationIdHere MDC is a mighty feature
```

Now when searching Splunk for 'AssumeProperCorrelationIdHere' you will fetch all log events containing this value. Also by using key-value format in log it is easy to construct splunk field using regex like "cid: \w+". This will allow you to have aggregate functions on correlation id. So you can do unique or count or whatever query.